# Drawing a circle on top of a path - HTML 5

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to draw a path by using `moveTo` and `lineTo`, and on top of the line of certain points I want to draw a small circle, indicating the point coordinates on the xy plane.

So far, I have the following:

```
function draw() 
{ 
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
if( canvas == NaN) alert('empty');  
var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 

context.beginPath(); 
context.strokeStyle= "black"; 
context.lineWidth = 4;

context.moveTo(zx, zy + my); 

    for(var s in resources)
    {
        var array = resources[s];  
        // foreach pair inside a series..
        for(var a in array)
        {
            var x = array[a]; 

            context.strokeStyle="black";    
            context.lineTo(zx + x[0] + 5, zy + my - x[1]);   
            context.stroke(); 
            context.beginPath(); 

            context.strokeStyle="red";  
            context.arc(zx + x[0] + 5, zy + my - x[1], 1, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);     
            context.stroke(); 
            context.closePath();  

        }

    }
}
```

Which results in drawing the path correctly, but I only see the red circle on the last point. Other points are hidden under the black path.

Comment: could you give us some sameple inputs for resources/zx/zy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to draw the arcs individually as separate paths, after you've drawn your main shape.